# Filter a list of records containing discriminated union members based on member underlying type

Tags: f#

Is there a way to do this?

```
type EntryDetails = 
| ADetails of TypeADetails
| BDetails of TypeBDetails
| ...


type Entry = { A, B, C, ... Details:EntryDetails}

let filter (list:list<Entry>) myType = List.filter (fun x -> x.Details is myType)
```

Please take note I would like myType to be a parameter and not hardcoded type.

I tried this but it obviously doesn't work:

```
let filterDetails (entry:Entry) detailType = match entry.Details with 
                                               | detailType -> true 
                                               | _ -> false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an exact solution to your question, but it's pretty close and easy to implement -- how about using a partial active pattern with `List.choose`, like so:

```
type EntryDetails =
    | ADetails of int
    | BDetails of byte
    | CDetails of string

type Entry = { Foo : unit; Bar : unit; Details : EntryDetails; }

module Patterns =
  let (|ADetails|_|) x =
      match x.Details with
      | ADetails _ -> Some x
      | _ -> None

  let (|BDetails|_|) x =
      match x.Details with
      | BDetails _ -> Some x
      | _ -> None

  let (|CDetails|_|) x =
      match x.Details with
      | CDetails _ -> Some x
      | _ -> None

module internal Test =
    let private testData =
        let baseData = { Foo = (); Bar = (); Details = ADetails 0; }
        [   { baseData with Details = ADetails 10; };
            { baseData with Details = BDetails 7uy; };
            { baseData with Details = BDetails 92uy; };
            { baseData with Details = ADetails 32; };
            { baseData with Details = CDetails "foo"; };
            { baseData with Details = BDetails 2uy; };
            { baseData with Details = ADetails 66; };
            { baseData with Details = CDetails "bar"; };
            { baseData with Details = CDetails "baz"; }; ]

    let results =
        testData
        |> List.choose Patterns.(|ADetails|_|)
```

If you paste that code into `fsi`, you should get the following output:

```
(* Snip ... removed irrelevant type signatures *)
module internal Test = begin
  val private testData : Entry list =
    [{Foo = null;
      Bar = null;
      Details = ADetails 10;}; {Foo = null;
                                Bar = null;
                                Details = BDetails 7uy;};
     {Foo = null;
      Bar = null;
      Details = BDetails 92uy;}; {Foo = null;
                                  Bar = null;
                                  Details = ADetails 32;};
     {Foo = null;
      Bar = null;
      Details = CDetails "foo";}; {Foo = null;
                                   Bar = null;
                                   Details = BDetails 2uy;};
     {Foo = null;
      Bar = null;
      Details = ADetails 66;}; {Foo = null;
                                Bar = null;
                                Details = CDetails "bar";};
     {Foo = null;
      Bar = null;
      Details = CDetails "baz";}]

  val results : Entry list =
    [{Foo = null;
      Bar = null;
      Details = ADetails 10;}; {Foo = null;
                                Bar = null;
                                Details = ADetails 32;};
     {Foo = null;
      Bar = null;
      Details = ADetails 66;}]
end
```

As you can see, the `Test.results` list is filtered so it only includes the `Entry` items whose `Details` field has type `ADetails`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is functionally exactly what I want. However I still have to write that boring boilerplate Patterns._ method every time I add a type to discriminated union. Oh well, i tried.